# uWSGI cron-like interface, signal based timers

Tags: python, uwsgi

I am trying to have a cron like process that gets run every 60 seconds.  I do not want it to be executed by every thread.  Is there a way to specify which uwsgi worker will respond to a signal?

I currently have uwsgi configured to have a master process, lazy mode, and 2 workers with 2 threads.

I have the following code directly in my wsgi file.

```
def sig_test(signum):
    print "do this thing" + signum

uwsgi.register_signal(99, "", sig_test)
uwsgi.add_timer(99, 60)
```

The signal registration segment gets run in both threads, and leads to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/local/wsgi.wsgi", line 153, in <module>
uwsgi.register_signal(99, "worker 1", sig_test)
ValueError: unable to register signal
Wed Jan 15 16:01:57 2014 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Wed Jan 15 16:01:57 2014 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Wed Jan 15 16:02:08 2014 - [uwsgi-signal] you have registered this signal in worker 2 memory area, only that process will be able to run it
Wed Jan 15 16:02:08 2014 - error managing signal 99 on worker 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Python decorators: [timer](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html#uwsgidecorators.timer) and possibly [spool](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html#uwsgidecorators.spool). Per the docs, *Signal-based decorators execute the signal handler in the first available worker*. However, in lazy mode the app is loaded and executed in each worker separately, and uWSGI is not smart enough to create the timer only once. The simplest fix would be using `shared-import` config option and init the timer there.

Comment: uwsgi is configured to use 'lazy mode'.  Per the docs, lazy mode _will instruct uWSGI to load the applications after each worker_.  This results in multiple timers that are set on two different signals.

If I disable lazy-mode, then the decorators (and my code above) work fine.